# Flutter - how use "non-linear" animation with LinearProgressIndicator?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I using LinearProgressIndicator in my app. I need use "non-linear" animation with LinearProgressIndicator. I need the indicator to move unevenly (a little slower a little faster).

This my current code:

```
  controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    upperBound: 1,
    animationBehavior: AnimationBehavior.preserve,
    duration: Duration(seconds: widget.duration),
  );
  ....
  controller.addListener(() {
     setState(() {
          .....
     });
  });
  ....
  LinearProgressIndicator(value: controller.value);
```

this works fine but is "linear"

I tried:

```
    TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
            tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 2),
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3500),
            builder: (context, value, _) =>  LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: value,
                  ),)
```

but it doesn't give "non-linear" animation. how do i get "non-linear" animation for LinearProgressIndicator ? is it possible?

Comment: `LinearProgressIndicator(value: curvedAnimation.value);` - where `curvedAnimation` is `CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: ...)`

Comment: thanks, it works

Comment: sure, your welcome